# R: How to split data into training and testing set, while preserving proportions & distributions of variables?

Tags: r, testing

Reproducible example:

```
library(caTools) #for sample.split function
set.seed(123)
#Creating example data frame
example_df <- data.frame(personID = > c(stringi::stri_rand_strings(1000, 5)),
                           sex = sample(1:2, 1000, replace=TRUE),
                           age = round(rnorm(1000, mean=50, sd=15), 0))

#Example of random splitting:
training_set <- example_df[sample.split(example_df$personID),]
test_set <- example_df[-c(training_set$personID),]

#evaluation of variables in test and training data sets:
  #Has to approximate 1 (in this case it's 1.2, which is too high)
  (sum(training_set$sex == 1) / sum(training_set$sex == 2)) / (sum(test_set$sex == 1) / sum(test_set$sex == 2)) 
  [1] 1.219139
  #Has to approximate 1 along the distribution (it's quite good, this is actually what i would expect)
  summary(training_set$age) / summary(test_set$age)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.7143  0.9756  1.0000  1.0032  1.0169  1.0000
```

Although sample.split function divided `age` appropriately (distributions match), proportion of males and females differ significantly in `sex` variable. What function to use for automatic and even split of data into multiple (in this example two) sets, while preserving proportions and distributions of variables?

Comment: Generally a good question. However, not entirly reproducible. Where does `sample.split` come from? What is the rogue `>` doing in the data.frame creation? I highly recommend you look into the [reprex](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex) package.

Answer (score 1):

The `caret` package will build balanced sets for you.  Check the package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.html) covering the basics.  For example:

```
inTrain <- createDataPartition(
  y = Sonar$Class,
  ## the outcome data are needed
  p = .75,
  ## The percentage of data in the
  ## training set
  list = FALSE
)
```